# android image is displayed the old one instead of new one when image is uploaded with same name

Tags: java, php, android

**ProfileActivity.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container,
            false);
    nama = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
    tanggal = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.birth);
    telepon = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.telepon);
    status = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    email = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    edit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit);

    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
     int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    session.checkLogin();
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    String nama1 = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_username);
    String tanggal1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_birthday);
    String image1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_image);
    String status1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_status);
    String telepon1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_telephone);
    String email1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_email);
    nama.setText("Nama: " + nama1);
    tanggal.setText("Tanggal Lahir : " + tanggal1);
    telepon.setText("No Telepon : " + telepon1);

    if (status1.equals("SA")) {
        status.setText("Status : Super Admin");
    } else if (status1.equals("A")) {
        status.setText("Status : Admin");
    } else {
        status.setText("Status : Sales");
    }
    email.setText("Email : " + email1);

    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = new EditProfileActivity();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            getActivity().setTitle("Edit Profile");
        }
    });
    String image_url = "url_name"
            + image1;

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, img);

    return rootView;
}
```

**EditProfileActivity.java**

```
session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        session.checkLogin();
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        telp1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_telephone);
        email1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_email);
        id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
        nama = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_username);
        image1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_image);
        tanggal = user.get(SessionManager.key_birthday);
        status = user.get(SessionManager.key_status);
        password1 = user.get(SessionManager.key_pass);
        oldpass1 = oldpass.getText().toString();
        newpass1 = newpass.getText().toString();
        retypepass1 = retypepass.getText().toString();
        int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        gmbr.setText(image1);
        telp.setText(telp1);
        email.setText(email1);
        oldpass.setText(password1);
        newpass.setText(password1);
        String image_url = "url_name"
                + image1;

        // ImageLoader class instance
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, img);

        changepic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                galleryIntent();
            }
        });

        editprof.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // if (!oldpass.equals(password1) ||
                // !retypepass.equals(newpass)) {
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Old Password Salah",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // } else {
                new editprofile().execute();
                // }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    protected void galleryIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK
                && data != null) {
            Uri Selectedimage = data.getData();
            img.setImageURI(Selectedimage);
        }
    }

    class editprofile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap images = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            images.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                    byteArrayOutputStream);
            String EncodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(
                    byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            String email2 = email.getText().toString();
            String telepon2 = telp.getText().toString();
            String newpass2 = newpass.getText().toString();
            String img2 = gmbr.getText().toString();

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> datatosend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            datatosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", EncodedImage));
            datatosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagename", img2));
            datatosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email2));
            datatosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telepon", telepon2));
            datatosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpass", newpass2));
            datatosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

            HttpParams httpParams = gethttprequestparam();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    EditProfileActivity.url_create_product);

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(datatosend));
                httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "edit profile berhasil",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            session.logoutUser();
        }

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();
    }

    public HttpParams gethttprequestparam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 1000 * 30);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 1000 * 30);
        return httpParams;
    }
```

**EditProfile.php**

```
<?php 
$response = array();


include('Connect.php');
$image= $_POST['image'];
$image1= $_POST['imagename'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$telepon= $_POST['telepon'];
$newpass= $_POST['newpass'];
$id= $_POST['id'];


$decodedimage = base64_decode("$image");
$image = 
file_put_contents("foldername/".$image1, $decodedimage);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "update user set image = '$image1' where iduser = '$id'");
$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "update user set email = '$email' where iduser = '$id'");
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "update user set phone = '$telepon' where iduser = '$id'");
$query3 = mysqli_query($con, "update user set password = '$newpass' where iduser = '$id'");

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

the main problem is when I edit profile with the same image name, the table user in database is updated and the image is uploaded with new one with same name but when I displayed image in android using imageloader, the image is displayed with old one instead of new one. how can i fix it?

**notes:** The image is replaced with new one when the image name is different(ex: the old one is a.JPG, the new one is b.JPG) but won't replaced with new one if the image name is still the same.

Comment: Because image is stored in cache, if image name is same it will not load again and again. It will simply load image from cache, to overcome this you need to remove your cache.

Comment: ok.. fixed now thanks.. I forgot to put clearcache in my code